# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' Array of System::String

Tags: .net, arrays, string, c++-cli

I have an object:

```
namespace Picture{
    class ref Picture{
        System::String^ path
        int picNumber;
    };
}
```

Then I try and make an array of them and fill my `path` inside my main:

```
TrackPicOnSlide = 2;
array<Picture::Picture^>^ ArrayPics = gcnew array<Picture::Picture^>(TrackPicOnSlide);
ArrayPics[0]->path = "HI";
```

But it gives me a run time error of:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PPTAuto.exe`

`Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new array of `Picture` but you are not filling the array itself with any pictures so when you try to access the element at location 0 you will get null which is why you are getting the exception, you should do something like:

```
TrackPicOnSlide = 2;
array<Picture::Picture^>^ ArrayPics = gcnew array<Picture::Picture^>(TrackPicOnSlide);
ArrayPics[0] = gcnew Picture;
ArrayPics[0]->path = "HI";
// etc..
```